# Original instruction set for the first ARM processor

Tags: instruction-set, arm

I'm studying ISAs and would really like to see the very first ISA that Sophie Wilson chose/put together when designing the very first ARM CPU while at Acorn Computers around 1983 or so.

From what I understand, they (she and Steve Furber) collaborated and chose the ideal instruction set for their planned processor, using the RISC paradigm they recently learned about.

Does anyone know of a copy of this instruction set (I would love to see Sophie Wilson's original design, before Steve Furber asked to cut out a few instructions that he felt weren't technically possible to physically fabricate)?

I've looked online and on various forums but couldn't find anything definitive. Maybe this was never published, but there must be some historical record?

It could just be a high-level overview: number of instructions, brief description of what each instruction does. It doesn't have to be the technical (official) specification, though that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/09/a-history-of-arm-part-1-building-the-first-chip/ lists 45 instructions. Not sure if that is before or after pruning any out.

Comment: This is a great start, thank you. Now searching "ARM v1" and finding a lot more resources: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/armv1

Comment: AFAIK ARMv1 is the first published ISA, post-clean-up.

Comment: Sophie Wilson has a [personal web page](https://www.sophie.org.uk/), with an e-mail address. If you want to know about pre-v1 ARM, I think your best bet is to ask her.

Comment: And if she responds, you might like to ask her for permission to provide the instruction set here in an answer, for those interested in it.

Comment: Please ask this on [stardot.org.uk](https://stardot.org.uk/forums/index.php). They have many ex-Acorn people there, and have put together several events where Sophie talks CPU design. I don't think they've ever located the original ARM simulator code, though